# Como tirar o espaço entre duas divs inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Alinhei duas `divs` lado a lado, porém ficou um espaço no meio delas, como retirar?

```css
#tudo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.desktop {
    display: block;
}
.img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
    <div class="desktop">
        <div class="img">
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode resolver isso usando uma gambiarra:

```
#tudo{
    font-size: 0;<<-------- esta
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
#tudo {
    font-size:0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.desktop {
    display: block;
}
.img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
    <div class="desktop">
        <div class="img">
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando nós identamos o código deixamos alguns espaços em branco, a propriedade `inline-block` vai colocar esse espaço entre os elementos.

Por exemplo, se eu pegar o teu código sem alteração nenhuma e colocá-lo `inline`na indentação ele também irá funcionar, veja :

```css
#tudo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.desktop {
    display: block;
}
.img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo"><div class="desktop"><div class="img"><a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%"></a></div><div class="img"><a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%"></a></div></div></div>
```

Então havendo o espaço o navegador inputa ao elemento um tamanho de fonte padrão, como não tem nenhum caractere além do caractere espaço, fica esse tamanho padrão, e atribuindo `0` a fonte ele fica com o tamanho `0`..Dhãããrrrr

Há outras formas de resolver isso. [Veja algumas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou perfeitamente! Só uma dúvida, pq isso resolveu meu problema? hahaha

Comment: Dei uma editada vê se fico bam...Vlw @JuanLima

Comment: Ficou ótimo, compreendi. Mais uma dúvida: dependendo de como vou rendimensionando a janela, as imagens ficam muito pequenas e descoladas. Sabe alguma forma de manter elas do mesmo tamanho e coladas? Agradeço desde já

Comment: Talvez setando o tamanho no `height e width`...

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você tem espaço entre os elementos: uma quebra de linha. Se você pegar o html que possui e comprimir, o problema já será resolvido:

```css
#tudo{text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;}.desktop{display: block;}.img{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id="tudo"> <div class="desktop"> <div class="img"> <a href="https://www.google.com"> <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%"> </a> </div><div class="img"> <a href="https://www.google.com"> <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%"> </a> </div></div></div>
```

Porém isso é ruim de visualizar. Então uma técnica pode ser colocar um comentário (`<!-- -->`) após os elementos, por exemplo:

```css
#tudo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.desktop {
    display: block
}
.img {
    display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo">
    <div class="desktop">
        <div class="img">
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%">
            </a>
        </div><!--
        --><div class="img">
            <a href="https://www.google.com">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" height="100%">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou então, não fechar a tag na mesma linha. Por exemplo:

```
<div> ... </div
><div> ...</div>
```

Comment: +1 Não sabia que esse espaçamento poderia interferir na exibição dos elementos. Interessante.

Answer (score 0):

seria bom você usar algum reset ou crie o seu proprio antes de começar a dar estilo a suas páginas pesquise sobre reset css..  Ex:

```
* {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que isso tem haver a pergunta?

Comment: Por padrão os navegadores já vem com alguns padrões de css.. se você não alterar eles podem ocasionar alguns espaçamentos indesejados como no caso.. e outros probleminhas.. como eu falei pesquise sobre reset css...

Comment: E você chegou a testar verificando se resolve o problema? Eu [testei](https://jsfiddle.net/4u1f5vah/) aqui a sua solução e não apresentou diferenças.

Comment: Eu apenas indiquei uma possível solução e indiquei ao mesmo estudar o assunto, pois o reset pode evitar diversos espaçamentos indesejado "como no caso" e se ele não utilizar um no seu projeto com certeza terá problemas do gênero.

Comment: @Drik eu entrei no mesmo questionamento do Anderson pelo fato que meu teste ficou da mesma maneira que está a pergunta.